# Hook ReadFile function in Excel

Tags: c++, excel, winapi, hook, readfile

I use XOR each byte with 'A' to generate encrypted file. And do that again to decrypt file -> Excel open decrypted file normally.

Now I want to open an encrypted file by Excel.

I hook the ReadFile API to decrypt the buffer before returning it.

But Excel displays

> Excel cannot be open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid

after reading the first 8 bytes.

The decrypted 8 bytes are `50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00`, which is the correct Open Office XML Signature and same with the original file.

Here is the `myReadFile` function:

```
BOOL WINAPI MyReadFile(
_In_ HANDLE hFile,
_Out_writes_bytes_to_opt_(nNumberOfBytesToRead, *lpNumberOfBytesRead) __out_data_source(FILE) LPVOID lpBuffer,
_In_ DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead,
_Out_opt_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead,
_Inout_opt_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped){

BOOL result = ReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, lpNumberOfBytesRead, lpOverlapped);
if (!result) {
    return result;
}

if (*lpNumberOfBytesRead == 0) {
    return result;
}
char* Buf = (char*)lpBuffer;
for (long i = 0; i < (*lpNumberOfBytesRead); i++)
{
    Buf[i] = Buf[i] ^ 'A';
}
return result;}
```

Does need hook other API to open encrypted file perfectly.

Comment: Have you verified your hook is being called?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, hook function has been called.

Comment: Modifying the xlsx file is not easy, I suggest you to manipulate the `.csv` file, and then save it as `.xlsx`.

Comment: Pretty sure you won't succeed in making this work. Even if you did, your files are trivial for any attacker to decrypt. Whatever problem you are trying to solve, this doesn't look like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Does need hook other API to open encrypted file perfectly.

Might be. A file migt be read other way after reading by `ReadFile` you've observed.

There are `ReadFileEx` and `ReadFileScatter`, though the first is rarely called, the second is even more rare. An application might directly call `NtReadFile`, though it is not much likely too.

What is more likely, is creating file mapping using `CreateFileMapping` or equivalent, and then using `MapViewOfFile` or equivalent. In this case I don't see a clean way of doing it via hooking.

It is also possilbe that is is read from some other process.

My suggestion is to get [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) tool, filter accesses to the target file path, and see all file operations. You can see call stacks of each operation and see what you need to hook.

Answer (score 0):

Excel call CreateFile with attribute FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.
If I hook CreateFile API and create file without FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, the code in the question now works fine.